# Flickr get latest photos ASP using API

Tags: asp.net, flickr

Hey I am currently using the following code

```
Dim flickr As New Flickr("apikey")

Dim test As New Photos
test = flickr.PhotosGetRecent(5, 5)

For Each [Photo] As FlickrNet.Photo In test.PhotoCollection
    Response.Write([Photo].ThumbnailUrl)
    Response.Write("<br>")
Next
```

But this only returns the Most Recent photos uploaded to flick in General, I only want my own ones. Is this possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have you use PhotosSearch instead, and sort by DateUploaded.

```
Dim flickr As New Flickr("apikey")

Dim options As New PhotoSearchOptions()
options.UserId = "myuserid@n01"
o.SortOrder = PhotoSearchSortOrder.DatePostedDescending
o.PerPage = 5
o.Page = 1

Dim test As Photos = flickr.PhotosSearch(options)

... etc
```